# Scrolling down in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How to scroll `myDiv` in the below code. This code is scrolling down the full browser window's content. I need only a division layer to be scrolled down.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myScroll(val)
            {
                x = document.getElementById(val);
                h= x.clientHeight;
                self.scrollTo(0,h);
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
<!--
#myDiv {
    background-color: #999999;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
-->
        </style>
</head>
    <body onLoad="myScroll("myDiv");">
        <div id="myDiv">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Donec tristique lectus sit amet est. Vivamus sit amet lacus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Morbi convallis sem nec lectus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Nullam in odio ac augue porttitor semper. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Nam leo. Morbi varius molestie felis. Etiam egestas. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Donec vitae mauris vitae nisi gravida pharetra. In molestie eros eu tellus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Suspendisse a mi vitae nulla vehicula lacinia. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Ut pellentesque lobortis ipsum. Quisque a leo. Curabitur tincidunt. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Fusce est velit, condimentum sed, convallis in, blandit hendrerit, eros.</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don’t see this script scolling anything, it just adds to the chatlog’s content. you are essentially asking: “please make this scroll for me”

Comment: It seems that you have forgotten to tell us what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @Pointy - This code is no more working. I need a code to auto scroll down the HTML DIV Layer

Comment: @flying sheep - Not really, I found this script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myScroll()
            {
                x = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                h= x.clientHeight;
                self.scrollTo(0,h);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="myScroll();">
        <div id="myDiv">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Donec tristique lectus sit amet est. Vivamus sit amet lacus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Morbi convallis sem nec lectus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Nullam in odio ac augue porttitor semper. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Nam leo. Morbi varius molestie felis. Etiam egestas. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Donec vitae mauris vitae nisi gravida pharetra. In molestie eros eu tellus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Suspendisse a mi vitae nulla vehicula lacinia. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Ut pellentesque lobortis ipsum. Quisque a leo. Curabitur tincidunt. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
                Fusce est velit, condimentum sed, convallis in, blandit hendrerit, eros.</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myScroll()
        {
            x = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            h= x.clientHeight;
            self.scrollTo(0,h);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="myScroll();">
    <div id="myDiv">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Donec tristique lectus sit amet est. Vivamus sit amet lacus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Morbi convallis sem nec lectus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Nullam in odio ac augue porttitor semper. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Nam leo. Morbi varius molestie felis. Etiam egestas. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Donec vitae mauris vitae nisi gravida pharetra. In molestie eros eu tellus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Suspendisse a mi vitae nulla vehicula lacinia. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Ut pellentesque lobortis ipsum. Quisque a leo. Curabitur tincidunt. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Fusce est velit, condimentum sed, convallis in, blandit hendrerit, eros.</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on css..

`div
{
    overflow: auto;
}`