# Scrolling down a HTML Layer

Tags: javascript, html

The following code is working well to scroll down the complete page. But I need only the DIV Layer to be scrolled down on HTML page load. Can anybody edit this code to scroll down DIV tag alone.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myScroll()
        {
            x = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            h= x.clientHeight;
            self.scrollTo(0,h);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="myScroll();">
    <div id="myDiv">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Donec tristique lectus sit amet est. Vivamus sit amet lacus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Morbi convallis sem nec lectus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Nullam in odio ac augue porttitor semper. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Nam leo. Morbi varius molestie felis. Etiam egestas. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Donec vitae mauris vitae nisi gravida pharetra. In molestie eros eu tellus. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Suspendisse a mi vitae nulla vehicula lacinia. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Ut pellentesque lobortis ipsum. Quisque a leo. Curabitur tincidunt. </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            Fusce est velit, condimentum sed, convallis in, blandit hendrerit, eros.</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: why don't you use the search function first? Even google could provide you with an answer

Comment: I tried all the night. Can you please show me at least one working code?

Comment: look here: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/web/js/scroll.html instead of `ScrollTop = 0` you have to use `ScrollTop = x.clientHeight`

Comment: Thanks! if you wish post it as an answer. I will mark it as best answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrolling down in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139414/scrolling-down-in-html)

Comment: @Brock - Its scrolling complete page not a fixed layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at: http://adp-gmbh.ch/web/js/scroll.html

you have to use `ScrollTop = x.clientHeight` instead of `ScrollTop = 0`